# XMLPullParser Special Characters

Tags: java, android, xml, special-characters, xmlpullparser

I use XMLPullParser to parse an XML document which unfortunately contains some special chars like:  or &amp... It seems that these chars interrupt the parsing procedure and only the text after these chars is shown but not before (if the special char appears in the middle of some text content). I have no control over this XML file so i have to fix this issues while parsing the document.

How can I do this? I already did some research and it showed up that I am able to implement an eventType called ENTITY_REF but I don't know how to deal with that approach.

Would be glad for some hints.

My Parser:

```
    while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
        if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            currentTag = xpp.getName();

        } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {

            if ("title".equals(currentTag)) {
                currentEvent.setTitle(xpp.getText());
                System.out.println("Event title: " + xpp.getText());
            } 
        } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
            if ("event".equals(xpp.getName())) {
                events.add(currentEvent);
                currentEvent = new Event();
            }
        }  else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.ENTITY_REF) {
            System.out.println("Entity REF: " + xpp.getText());
        }


        eventType = xpp.nextToken();
    }
```

Comment: i have try with domparser if u are interested for that code than i will answer for this question

Comment: not interested in DOm because it is too slow for my application. although thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Like SAX, XMLPullParser is a very low-level parsing interface, one that achieves high performance at considerable cost in usability. The parser is free to break text nodes up into fragments, and your code is required to accept a sequence of fragments and assemble them into the actual string value.

Comment: allright fixed it with a String Builder which assembles fragments into one string.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you extend `DefaultHandler` it is much easier to use and makes your code more reusable. I think you won't face such problem.

Comment: SAX has exactly the same problem that the parser can deliver text nodes split into multiple calls, and the application needs to assemble them. It's the most common cause of problems reported by SAX users on StackOverflow.